# Need Help IDing SPD Pedal

Tags: mountain-bike, pedals, spd, identify-this-bike

Anyone know who makes these and which model it is? In the middle of the pedal I can kind of make out "C (possibly, not 100% sure)" "ARV" "E (also not 100% sure, just guessing)".[image: pedals]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a pair of Forté Carve pedals. Forté is a house brand of [Performance Bicycles](http://www.performancebike.com/). I checked their website, but this particular model of pedal doesn't appear to be available any longer.

[image]

(*photo from [College Tri blog](https://collegetri.wordpress.com/tag/pedals/)*)

Here's another photo that shows the "CARVE" logo with the stylyized "V" engraved into the cross piece that matches the letters you found on your pedals:

[image]

(*photo from [mtbr.com](http://forums.mtbr.com/general-discussion/anyone-ever-use-forte-carve-spd-pedals-605993.html)*)

Comment: Johnny is absolutely right. Origin8, (J&B's House brand) sells a very similar pedal and I believe most performances now stock that one. 
<img src="http://www.jbi.bike/web/images/new_800/41813.jpg"></img>